# Wireless connectivity for Xbox gaming?

Tags: xbox-360

I was wondering, is wireless gaming any good an the Xbox 360. I recently purchased the xbox 360 S, and it has a built in wi-fi option. I don't have a wired internet connection to where my Xbox is located. So I was thinking of purchasing a new wireless router for Xbox gaming.

Is this a bad choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a computer guy and a gamer, I've always preferred a solid wired connection. However, with wireless technologies such as 802.11n that isn't really that big a deal any more, even 802.11g is still suitable for good gaming.

Your ping times will definitely suffer a little bit when playing wireless instead of a cabled connection, but it won't be a bad choice. If you value a slightly (very small increase here) better reaction time, then a wired connection is the way to go (as in the case of first person shooters, fighting games, etc) but if you're using it for things like NetFlix or streaming media/downloading DLC, indie games, etc. Wireless will work just fine.

Edit: I just looked up the specs for the 360S, if you get a wireless router capable of broadcasting at 802.11n you won't have any problems (assuming you don't have any other **major** types of wireless interference [a cordless phone doesn't count]). Just make sure that you set up your wireless network to broadcast on a channel that isn't in use nearby. The standard channels are 1, 6, or 11 because they allow for the least amount of overlap if they run into another signal.